# How to order attribute assignments in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I code a rails shop.
I have orders, products and line_items (with counts)

I now want to create a new line item.

My form comes back in a request and the params are set up just fine.
I do assign_attributes

I'd like to create a new line item,
but I need to have the assignments in a specific order.

Actually first of all the order should be assigned to the line item first,
next the the product should be assigned,
and only then the count shall be assigned.
(aka count= depends on both order and product already being assigned)

Aka order of assignment of attributes matters here.

I override assign_attributes here, to put the attributes in the right order.
Does someone else also use this trick?

Is there a gem out there to do that for me?
(like ordering the attribute asignments in assign_attributes)

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this would be to place each sub-step into separate methods and call them sequentially in an exposed method. I would also recommend against overriding #assign_attributes to prevent ambiguity and uncertainty to what is being called. Good code is readable code.

```
def assign_order_attributes( order_params = {} )  
    step_1
    step_2
    step_3
end
```